# Endpoint throws Invalid Argument if output is not read

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I've compiled [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html) and tried to use PHP to connect to the server. When connecting, it's meant to write text back to the client. If I read the output using PHP, the server runs fine - if I don't read the output, occasionally the server prints `remote_endpoint: Invalid argument` and then stops. Is there a fix for this (like catching the error)? I wanted to use this example to write my own server that returned some data. I don't want it to crash if someone is connecting to it but not reading the output. I use Mac OSX 10.8.3, with GCC 4.8 and C++11 enabled.

Comment: The server doesn't care whether your client reads the message or not. Perhaps, the client closes the connection prematurely?

Comment: Try using 'nc' (netcat) to connect to the server?

Also, if you're not beholden to boost, check out [libevent](http://libevent.org/)

Comment: @IgorR. I think that's what's happening, yeah.

Comment: @kfsone It shouldn't matter what client I use, if the server crashes, then people could use custom clients for malicious purposes. I'll try it anyways.

Comment: You should wrap with `try..catch` every callback which working async, or thread which run this handler in `io.run()` will get an exception, that is no good i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this server to catch exceptions and go on, just change `main` as follows:

```
int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  tcp_server server(io_service);
  while(true)
    try
    {
      io_service.run();
      break; 
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
      std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no need to `reset()` if `run()` was not stopped, exceptions do not stop the service. Or i am wrong?

Comment: @PSIAlt Correct, I've fixed this. Thanks!